# nodejs express router reprocess request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router, nodemailer

my express router is processing a request twice and i don't know why, causing send emails twice too
I'll show my frontend code and my backend code

FRONT: it's ok, it only send request once

```
async cargarZip() {
  let formData = new FormData();
  let zipFile = document.querySelector("#archivoZip");
  formData.append("archivoZip", zipFile.files[0]);
  await axios.post(
    CONSTANTES.URL_RUTA_SERVICIOS + "cargas/cargar-zip", 
    formData,
    {headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
     })
     .then(function (response) {
       // actions
     })
     .catch(function () {});
}
```

BACK: for some reason, router reprocess the request

```
    cargasResultadosRouter.post('/cargar-zip', mdAutenticacion.verificaToken,
        async function (req, res) {
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    moment.locale('es')
    let fecha = moment().format("L").split("/").join("-")
    let hora = moment().format('LTS')

    let file = req.files.archivoZip

    let fileName = file.name.replace(/ /, '_')
    console.log(fecha, hora, "cargas/cargar-zip", "Llegó:", fileName);

    let dir = './resultadosParaEnviar';

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        console.log(dir, "Creado");
    }

    let ruta = "/opt/app/ServiciosCliexCovid/OM_ServicioCliexCovid/public/resultadosParaEnviar/"

    let rutaArchivoZip = ruta + fecha + " " + fileName
    file.mv(rutaArchivoZip, async function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500);
        } else {
            let rutaArchivoFolder = ruta + fecha + "_" + fileName.split(".")[0];
            if (!fs.existsSync(rutaArchivoFolder)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(rutaArchivoFolder);
                console.log(rutaArchivoFolder, "Creado");
            }
            await decompress(rutaArchivoZip, rutaArchivoFolder).then(async files => {
                await esperarTiempo(100)
                console.log(fileName, 'Extraido');
                let emails = []
                for (const [index, file] of files.entries()) {
                    await esperarTiempo(100)
                    let codigo = file.path.match(/(\d+)/);
                    console.log(index, "Archivo Encontrado:", codigo, "de", files.length);
                    if (codigo) {
                        let archivos = []
                        archivos.push({
                            filename: file.path,
                            path: rutaArchivoFolder + '/' + file.path
                        })
                        // Get email
                        let correo = await BD.CargarResultadosDao.CorreoPruebaMolecular(codigo[0])

                        emails.push({
                            correo: correo,
                            archivos: archivos
                        })
                        // Sends email
                        if (correo !== '') {
                            await enviarCorreoConPruebaMolecular(correo, archivos)
                            await esperarTiempo(1500)
                        }

                    } else {
                        console.log("NO ENCONTRO:", file.path);
                    }
                }
                res.json(emails);
            });                
      }
    })
})

function esperarTiempo(tiempo) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("resolved");
        }, tiempo);
    });
}
```

LOG says:
24-09-2020 15:33:44 cargas/cargar-zip Llegó: OMNIA_MEDICA 10-09.zip
from:
console.log(fecha, hora, "cargas/cargar-zip", "Llegó:", fileName);

And 2 minutes after says:
24-09-2020 15:35:58 cargas/cargar-zip Llegó: OMNIA_MEDICA 10-09.zip
from:
console.log(fecha, hora, "cargas/cargar-zip", "Llegó:", fileName);

Without a resend from front

I'm using Vue in front and the server is on nginx

Comment: Do you have some kind of load balancer in front of this?  If the response takes too long, the load balancer might resend the request because it didn't receive a response after some time.  The 2 minute delay makes me think it's because the response is taking too long or not being received?

Comment: Yes, it has. I think it can be the problem. I really don't know about that function of load balancer, but do you think that i should configure the time of response maybe ? And, do you know where is it ? thanks

Comment: If  your response is taking 2 minutes, then that to me is a design problem of your API that you should fix.  Calls should not take that long to return; they should be made asynchronous so that you can return immediately and then the caller can poll for status (or otherwise get notified) if the request is complete.

Comment: Hello Joe, I think the process for the response takes aproximatetly 4 minutes, and i know that is normal. correct me if i'm wrong please. I know that navigator can wait normally